# "Junk after expression" using GNU Assembler macro

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, preprocessor, gnu-assembler

I'm roughly following [this guide](https://littleosbook.github.io/#creating-a-generic-interrupt-handler) on setting up a simple OS. It gives some assembly intended for NASM but I am using the GNU Assembler.

At the top of my assembly file I am using

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
```

I have defined a macro like so

```
.macro no_error_code_handler num
.global interrupt_handler_\num
.type interrupt_handler_\num, @function
interrupt_handler_\num:
    push dword 0
    push dword \num
    jmp common_int_handler
.endm
```

If it matters, `common_int_handler` is defined nearby as

```
common_int_handler:
    pushad
    call int_handler # This is a C function
    popad
    add esp, 8
    iret
```

And then lastly I have the line

```
no_error_code_handler 0
```

Which I would hope expands to something like

```
.global interrupt_handler_0
.type interrupt_handler_0, @function
interrupt_handler_0:
    push dword 0
    push dword 0
    jmp common_int_handler
```

When compiling I get an error from the `no_error_code_handler 0` line saying

```
Assembler messages:
Error: junk `0' after expression
Error: junk `0' after expression
```

Does it have something to do with defining the type as a function even though it doesn't behave like a normal function? Should I be using `.exitm` somewhere since I leave after the `iret` instruction?

Comment: For efficiency, you only need to save/restore the call-clobbered registers.  Compiler-generated functions already preserve the call-preserved regs as part of the calling convention.

Comment: The interrupt code is also lacking a `CLD` instruction before making a call to _C_ code (function `int_handler`). You have to ensure the direction flag is set forward for string instructions. If the code being interrupted happened to have issued a `STD` instruction and the interrupt code used a x86 string instruction then the code interrupt would likely not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are causing the error

```
push dword 0
push dword \num
```

`dword` is not valid in this context.

```
push 0
push \num
```

Removing dword solves the issue

Comment: It's not *because* you specified `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  That wouldn't be valid AT&T syntax either.  GAS's intel_syntax mode is NOT like NASM; it's more like MASM.